# Call a overloading extension method in class

Tags: c#, extension-methods, method-resolution-order

Consider following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new Test();
        t.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Test
{

}

public static class TestHelper
{
    public static string ToString(this Test test)
    {
        return "HashValue of test instance: " + test.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

How can I just call my overloading (at least VS tells me that `ToString()` has `+1 overload`) extension method? Since `Test` inherites (along ALL classes in the .NET Framework afaik) from `object`. The class `object` has a implentation of `ToString()` that returns something like `<namespace-wher-the-class-is-locatet.<class-name>`.
But what if I want to `ToString()` my own implementation that takes no other parameter?

And NO, I don't want to implement `ToString()` inside of my class. I want to do it as a extension method. (Like extension for SecureString to convert it back from unmanaged, encrypted to managed, decrypted)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see any sense in this.. can someone explain how this could be usefull?

Comment: As I wrote: for example as extension for **System.Securety.SecureString** to convert it back to an readable string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call it directly and you can not change it because method resolution choose the instance member over extension method.

```
TestHelper.ToString(t)
```